# 'VirtualButtonBehaviour' does not contain a definition for 'RegisterOnButtonPressed'

Tags: c#, augmented-reality

I have just started creating AR apps and I am stuck in one of the project of adding a virtual button in an AR App - I have written the following C# code -

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class bScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private GameObject vbButtonObject;
    public Animator cubeAni;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        vbButtonObject = GameObject.Find("actionButton");
        vbButtonObject.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterOnButtonPressed(OnButtonPressed);
        vbButtonObject.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterOnButtonReleased(OnButtonReleased);
    }

    public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button Down");
    }

    public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
    {

    }


}
```

and the console is showing an error - " 'VirtualButtonBehaviour' does not contain a definition for 'RegisterOnButtonPressed' and no accessible extension method 'RegisterOnButtonPressed' accepting a first argument of type 'VirtualButtonBehaviour' could be found".
Please help me to solve it as I have searched a lot abut this but I am not getting a way out of this problem.

Comment: you probably need to upgrade Vuforia version

Answer (score 0):

Use higher version of vuforia thats the only solution